# Android Set tabOrder from rigt to left or change direction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

default order tab in my this code is left to right and i want to change that to right to left or change that direction to right.

My code:

```
    /*
    * TAB LISTENER ON -----------------------
    */
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //--------- TAB 1
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search);
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);

    //--------- TAB 2
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

    tab2.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    //--------- TAB 3
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText(R.string.title_section3);
    tab3.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment XML:**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccc"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:context="ir.tsms.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

**fragment_main XML:**

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.tsms.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="ir.tsms.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something from your question, you could simply change the order that you call `actionBar.addTab` in code.

Comment: add tab to actionBar in the reverse order

Comment: @AshaSoman can i customize order?

Comment: What u mean by customizing order?If tab3 is the first tab add tab3 to the actionbar at first before adding any other tabs

Comment: @AshaSoman that right. i want to active or enable last by default. in this action first tab is active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tab3 is your first tab, then add tab3 to the actionbar at first before adding any other tabs

```
actionbar.addTab (tab1, true);
```

This can be used for  setting the tab as selected

Answer (score 2):

Add your last tab as:

```
actionBar.addTab(tab3, true);
```

So it will be selected.